# .data symbols equivalent to .text labels?

Tags: assembly, mips

It is understood that the labels that come in the `.text` section of an assembly program are representative of the address of the following instruction.

Is it the same idea with the symbols we see in the `.data` section ? i.e. *"The label is representative of the base address of whatever follows"*.

Does this apply anywhere in the program ?

I'm a NOOB in assembly, learning MIPS as a part of coursework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically stated the answer yourself, a label is representative of a location in your assembly code. The section is irrelevant.

(You misused the term "base address" though)

Comment: Thank you ! What should have been the correct term ? I thought doing `str: .asciiz "Hello"` and then doing `la $t0, str` would load the address of 'H' in `t0`, Hence  _Base Address_.

Comment: You have the principle right, it's just that the term *Base Address* designs the reference address from which you calculate relative addresses once loaded in memory (VA = BaseAddress + RVA)